# My moving background won't stretch, but rather have a static place. I can't seem to change that

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a moving background made with javascript and now I want to stretch my background. I used and search for many ways, but couldn't find any solutions. It won't show me the text (it's behind the background) and the picture stays static.

I already tried those solutions with background: cover for example.

This is my css code for the background picture.

```
#section1 { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("../IMG/Background.png");
}
```

Maybe this is also useful for the problem at hand, but i already have this working.

```
var i=1;

function move(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById("section1").style.backgroundPosition=i+"px";
}

window.onload = function(){
    var move1 = setInterval(move, 30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc on mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) it would seem that the value you assign to `backgroundPosition` is not valid.
It could be (among other formats), like this :
`background-position: 50px 100px;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `background-size: cover;` to the styles:

```css
#section1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("../IMG/Background.png");
}
```